# iOS 9 - Xcode: "Follows Readable Width" programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, ios9

In iOS 9, there is an option in the Xcode SIZE inspector called "Follows Readable Width" which will place padding on the left/right sides of a view so that it won't stretch out so far (especially on iPads) in order to make the content easier to read.

(You can see an example of this on the Twitter app when placed in landscape on iPhone 6/6s plus.)

Anyway, I cannot seem to find how to do this programmatically. In the Xcode SIZE inspector, it's just a checkbox you set. It's obviously a boolean value you can set on any UIView or anything that inherits from it. I just cannot seem to find anything close to it.

Anyone ever set this programmatically? Please see the attached screenshot.

Oh, I *can* find the 'Preserve Superview Margins' just fine, just not the 'Follows Readable Width' property.

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated answer. Setting by code is possible, but only for UITableViews.

Comment: @FrederikA.Winkelsdorf Well, that updated answer is wrong. The `readableContentGuide` can be pinned for any view.

Comment: @matt: Sorry, but that's what I wrote. "If you want to pin your layout to it, create a set of NSLayoutConstraints by Code and connect them to the ```readableContentGuide``` anchor points". The question here was about setting this particular *property* by code. Fact: The *property* can only be set for a tableView. Please take your time and reconsider your down vote.. What you state in that one-liner is fully included in my answer. Shaking my head now.

Comment: Okay, I see that now. But your update muddies the waters, the way it's written. I can't remove my down vote unless you edit your answer somewhat.

Comment: @matt Thank you! That's a good point I can pick up, I am going to rephrase my answer. My update was intended for a likely use case where a property exists (and working around by the anchor points is unneeded), that's why I added that case three weeks later: Stating there is no property at all was wrong. Anyhow, while it is both correct, it's likely more helpful to point that clearly out. Thanks for your contribution :)

Comment: @matt done! I'm curious what you think about the edit.. Trying to improve my english each and every day :) But that's a meta topic.

Answer (score 12):

The **"Follow Readable Width"** option you can set in the Interface Builder is handled by code in two different ways:

1) **UITableViews**

There is a property for `UITableView` to trigger the readable width:

```
if #available(iOS 9, *) {
    tableView.cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth = false
}
```

So this is comparable to the handling of the preserving of superview margins, which is done by code with `preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = true/false`.

From the api docs for `cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth`:

> A Boolean value that indicates whether the cell margins are derived
>   from the width of the readable content guide.

This property is the equivalent to the option in Interface Builder.

2) **UIViews**

Sadly there is no single property like the above publicly available with the UIKit api. But the quote from the api docs already gives a hint:

Instead of a single property to toggle with `true/false`, every UIView provides a `readableContentGuide` property. That property is part of the new `UILayoutGuide` class (iOS 9 and later).

To understand what that is and how to use it, let's take a look at what the **"Follow Readable Width"** option does: If you enable that option in interface builder, a set of constraints is automatically added to that view.

The `readableContentGuide`basically provides you with a set of these anchor points.

If you want to pin your layout to the readable width by code, create a group of NSLayoutConstraints and connect them to the anchor points of `readableContentGuide`. This has to be wrapped in an `#available(iOS 9, *)` block, too.

**Updated 04/21/16**
Added info about UITableView cellLayoutMarginsFollowReadableWidth

**Updated 04/22/16**
Rephrased to make things clear. Thanks to @matt for making me aware of!

Comment: How can we use readableContentGuide without using autolayout? Is this property available as a plain CGFloat?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick Haven't tried that. You could try to access the readableContentGuide's array of layoutGuides. Each of them should return a CGRect for it's layoutFrame variable. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622644-readablecontentguide, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilayoutguide/1619657-layoutframe. hth!

Comment: Thanks for the UIView part. I don't understand why the checkbox only applies correctly to cells and not to more generic views like a textview :/